# How can I create a constructor?

Tags: powershell

In my last question, Stack Overflow helped me fix an error with my methods, so now I have a class like

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    [void] AM([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
        $This.C = $True
    }
}
```

Which has the method `AM`, but how can I make constructors like

```
[myClass]::myConstructor()
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7#constructor, I think you are confusing static operators and constructors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell syntax is generally similar to C# syntax since they both use the .NET framework. It seems like you are confusing **static operators** and **constructors**.

**Constructors** are basically the inputs the class could take. For example:

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    [void] AM([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
        $This.C = $True
    }
}
```

In your class,

```
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }
```

Is the constructor. They contain the properties from the `::new()` static operator (This may have caused your confusing).

A **static operator** is like a method but with static operators (`::`). You define static operators with `Static [void]` or a different type depending on the output type you want. Example:

```
    Static [void] AS() {
        Write-Host "Test"
    }
```

In a class like

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    [void] AM([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
        $This.C = $True
    }

    Static [void] AC() {
        Write-Host "Test"
    }
}
```

You can call the static operator with

```
[myClass]::AS()
```

with the output

```
Test
```

Which you can't do with methods:

```
PS C:\> [myClass]::AM("Argument")
Method invocation failed because [myClass] does not contain a method named 'AM'.
At line:1 char:1
+ [myClass]::AM()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

*Technically* static operators are treated as methods but they are different.

Of course you can also have arguments in your static operator as well, they are basically methods just called differently:

```
class Main
{
    [int]$A
    [string]$B
    [bool]$C
}

class myClass : Main
{
    myClass(){
        $This.A = 1
        $This.B = "Property"
        $This.C = $False
    }

    Static [void] AC([string]$Argument) {
        Write-Host $Argument
    }
}
```

and

```
PS C:\> [myClass]::AC("Test")
Test
PS C:\> [myClass]::AC("Argument")
Argument
```